# WORHP 13.2 Crashing when running the example file

Tags: matlab, worhp

i am currently trying to run WORHP 13.2 for MATLAB on a new computer.

```
worhp_setup_windows
```

works fine up until the example call in line 93. In the example.m file, the

```
worhp(wData, wCallback)
```

in line 62 is freezing and finally crashing MATLAB without an error message. This is all the output I get:

Welcome to WORHP's direct call MATLAB interface.

To get started, your installation of MATLAB must be correctly
configured to compile C and C++ files using "mex".
You can configure the compiler in MATLAB using these commands:
mex -setup C
mex -setup C++
For further information see this documentation:
doc worhp_setup_windows

Compiling WORHP's direct call MATLAB interface now...
worhp.cpp
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
MEX completed successfully.
WORHP's direct call MATLAB interface was compiled correctly.

Running WORHP's direct call MATLAB example now...

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 2010 and 2015-2019 (x64).

Sorry if I missed any basic installation.